# the impact of drop in oil prices financial markets performance and prospects?

Tags: stock-markets, markets, yahoo-finance, financial-advisor, crude-oil

Supporting that there is a correlation between oil prices and  stock market. What could be the implications of low oil prices on the financial markets performance and prospects?

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conventional wisdom is that the market is always highly correlated with the price of oil. And yet, some researchers at the Federal Reserve Bank of Cleveland and the  International Monetary Fund have concluded [otherwise](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/030415/how-does-price-oil-affect-stock-market.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Irrelevant. See, the point is not that the oil price got cheaper. The point is that the most companies in the financial market face some brutal economic impact REGARDLESS OF THE OIL PRICE. Take an airline. If you have NO passengers, the cheap oil price (and thus fuel price) does not really give you a boost. The economy right now is in a position that the most related fundamental factors are irrelevant for most companies as their core business is impacted.